# KVM Virt-Manager Error: No active connection to Installed on

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

When I tried to install new virtual machine in virt-manager, virtualization - localhost (QEMU) is not connected.

It shows Error: No active connection to installed on.
How to fix this problem.

Comment: Could you please be more specific: When and where does it show the error? Is that the complete error message? Please add screenshots of your virt-manager window and the error message to yourquestion.

Answer (score 6):

You are likely going to need to make sure your user owns the `libvirt` socket, change out the `username:username` with your actual username

```bsh
sudo chown username:username /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
```

Comment: After trying all of the other answers here, this is what made it finally work! Thanks!

Comment: This is the way. This fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 5):

1. Verify you have all packages you need

   ```
   sudo apt install -y qemu-kvm libvirt0 libvirt-bin virt-manager bridge-utils
   sudo systemctl enable libvirt-bin
   ```
2. Verify that libvirtd and libvirt-bin are up and running

   ```
   sudo service libvirtd status
   sudo service libvirt-bin status
   ```
3. ```
    sudo systemctl reboot
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your username is part of the libvirt group.
Try running `sudo adduser <username> libvirt`.  This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: sudo usermod -a -G libvirt <username> if the user already exists

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the error when trying to run it right after the installation.

I tried restarting the `libvirtd` service in that same session but with no success.

I tried logging out and logging back in still with no success.

But after rebooting the machine, all was fine.

Comment: Most of the other answers here are listing out stuff you definitely *shouldn't* have to do on a modern linux distro.  Rebooting did the trick for me just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the libvirtd service:

```
sudo service libvirtd stop
sudo service libvirtd start
```